# Too much padding around Button's Text

Tags: android, textview, android-button

I have a fragment that takes up the whole screen, with Buttons and a SeekBar which scale to fit it, as well as fixed size TextViews. I use linear horizontal and vertical layouts with weights to achieve this.

The problem is I can't get the button text large enough without it making the buttons expand in size. For some reason, any text size greater than about 35sp makes the button expand, no matter how big the button is. This screen shot shows the button sizes have plenty of space for the text:

[image]

Ideally I would like the "<" and ">" characters to fill the buttons. (I was going to programmatically change the font size according to the button size, e.g. for different screen sizes) but haven't tried since I can't even get the static layout to work.

***Edit: I would like to avoid images, since if I had 15 buttons, and 8 buckets, that would be 120 images I need!***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/VerticalLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" >

    <!-- ........ -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trackTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trackPreviousButton"
            style="android:buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_track_previous"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trackNextButton"
            style="android:buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_track_next"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        style="@style/tallerBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <!-- ........ -->

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried adding the following line to Buttons, but it only makes a small difference, if any:

```
android:padding="0dp"
```

Advice on getting the font height to fill the buttons without padding is my primary question. (But if the problem of dynamically sizing the text to fill the buttons for different screen sizes can be solved at the same time, that would be brilliant).

Edit: it turns out that using larger font sizes affects the effect of weighting for the height of the linear layouts, which is why there seemed to be padding - larger font size increased the button size, not because of the padding (which was 0) but because of the weighting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Button` is not the right widget for your purpose. Use an `ImageButton` (or even an `ImageView`) instead.

> I was going to programmatically change the font size according to the button size, e.g. for different screen sizes

Your current approach will land you in a lot of problems regarding proper sizing of your UI components. Given the plethora of android devices out there, screen size is just one aspect of the problem. You will also be dealing with varying screen densities. Best approach would be to put size/density buckets (drawable-mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi) to use. Help android in working for you.

Use `drawables` to indicate `next` and `previous`. If you're worried about the drawables being too small for tablet screens, create appropriate drawable resources/folders:

```
// Phones - 4 to 7 in
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi

// Tablets - 7 to 10 in
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi

// Tablets - 10 in
drawable-xlarge-mdpi
```

This list may not be exhaustive. Consider doing some research before finalizing your size/density buckets.

Output:

@ drawable size 32dp:

[image]

@ drawable size 64dp

[image]

Now it becomes quite straightforward - finalize drawable size by visual inspection on a phone, on a 7 inch tablet, and on a 10 inch tablet. Then use density scales to create and store appropriately sized drawable in the folders I mentioned above. Let android deal with what bucket to pick from.

Comment: Thank you - I was hoping to avoid this, as this means creating a LOT of images. In my app I have about 15 icons, so if I want 8 buckets, that's 120 images! I am utterly shocked with Google for this. It seems really poor. I don't suppose you know why Google essentially turned their back on SVG in favour of bitmaps?

Comment: Say I have a font.ttf file that has all the icons I need, is there a quick way of exploding it into the various drawables? Either at compile time, pre-compile time, or even runtime?

Comment: @Jodes I had similar questions when I first started dabbling with Android. Unfortunately, this is a necessary evil. There's a very informative post on use of SVGs on mobile platform here: [link](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/11/04/about-those-vector-icons.html). The author discusses the topic in quite some detail. During my research, I also found some performance-related problems with the use of SVGs. `Dianne` mentions some of these issues [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/Android-developers/svg/android-developers/_marNfJZamY/s1D66q9jwT4J).

Comment: @Jodes On an app I am working on, my drawable folders currently hold a total of 1100 files. This number will of course go down as the project nears completion. Any way, the closest thing to SVGs that android supports natively is the family of xml drawables: `ShapeDrawables`, `LayerDrawables` etc. These drawables are defined in xml and placed in the `res/drawable` folder - `they need not be placed in more than one density bucket if you define their size in `dp(density-pixels)`. So, no `drawable-ldpi/-mdpi/-hdpi/-xhdpi/-etc.`.

Comment: @Jodes Mind you, xml drawables _will_ have to be defined with appropriate size changes and placed in `drawable-large/-xlarge` folders. But there is a way to circumvent this - define `values/dimens.xml`, `values-large/dimens.xml` and `values-xlarge/dimens.xml` and add a new dimension to each of these files, say `drawable_width`. Now, you are free to assign a value to `drawable_width` - example - `16dp` in case of `values/dimens.xml`, `24dp` for `values-large/dimens.xml`, and `32dp` for `values-xlarge/dimens.xml` - android will choose the appropriate size based on device.

Comment: @Jodes Automation - there's an android icon generator that resizes icons according to design guidelines - [link](https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer). It works for both `pngs`and `9-patch` files. You will also find tools at this link useful - [link](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/). For font icons, I suggest you take a look at this library project - [link](https://github.com/shamanland/fonticon). If this seems a bit overwhelming, we can have a chat about this - you can leave a comment here linking to the chatroom.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is by default buttons include a `minHeight` attribute. I had the same problem and solved it with just a single line of code in my `XML` file:

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick and easy solution to your problem!
Auto-sizing text in Android is fiendishly difficult in my experience, especially when padding is involved. I would advise that instead of using an angle bracket character, you use a drawable - there are plenty of arrow icons available online - and an `ImageButton`. For example:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/trackNextButton"
        style="android:buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
```

By using different [ScaleTypes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) you can alter the stretching of the image. Even better, the screen sizes problem is solved because you can add different drawables for different densities.

Answer (score 0):

Use minWidth="0" or "1" to reduce the horizontal padding on a text Button.